# dimension of abstract nonsingular curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I have a question about a claim in Hartshorne's proof of Ch. I, Theorem 6.9 which states that the abstract nonsingular curve $C_K$ is isomorphic to a nonsingular projective curve.

The setup: let $k = \bar{k}$ be an algebraically closed field, and $K$ a function field of dimension $1$ over $k$ (that is, $K$ is a finitely generated $k$-extension of transcendence degree $1$ over $k$).  $C_K$ is the set of all DVR's of $K/k$ (DVR's $R$ with fraction field $K$ and $k \subseteq R$); we give it a topology by defining the closed sets to be the finite subsets and $C_K$ itself.

The first step in the proof is to show that $C$ has a finite open cover $\{U_1, \ldots, U_\ell\}$, where each $U_i \cong V_i$ for some nonsingular affine curve $V_i$.  Then embed
$$
V_i \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^{n_i} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n_i}
$$
and let $Y_i$ denote the closure of $V_i$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n_i}$.  Then $Y_i$ is a projective variety for each $i$, and there's a morphism $\varphi_i : U_i \to Y_i$ which is an isomorphism onto its image.

Next, $C- U_i$ is a finite set of points, so there's a unique extension $\bar{\varphi}_i : C \to Y_i$ of $\varphi_i$.  Let $\prod_{i=1} ^\ell Y_i$ denote the product of the projective varieties $Y_i$ which is a projective variety itself.  Define $\varphi : C \to \prod_{i=1} ^\ell Y_i$ by
$$
\varphi (P) := \prod_{i=1} ^\ell \bar{\varphi}_i (P)
$$
and let $Y$ denote the closure of the image of $\varphi$.  Then $Y$ is a projective variety, and $\varphi : C \to Y$ is a morphism with dense image.

**Question:** why does it follow (as Hartshorne includes paranthetically) that $Y$ is a curve?

I've tried appealing directly to the topological definition of dimension (length of longest chain of distinct irreducible closed subsets) to no avail.  I've also tried to think of a clever open cover of $Y$ and then use the fact that $\dim Y$ is the sup of dimensions of the covering subsets, but still haven't gotten it.

Comment: The dominant morphism $\varphi$ induces an field extension $K(Y)\subseteq K(C)$. So the dimension of $Y$ must $\leq 1$ by 1.8A(a).

Comment: @Jerry.Li that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer consisting of the answer from the comments in order to mark this question as answered once this is upvoted or accepted.

> The dominant morphism $\varphi$ induces an field extension $K(Y)\subset K(C)$. So the dimension of $Y$ must $\leq 1$ by 1.8A(a). – [**Jerry.Li**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/641369/jerry-li)